# Методы объекта this

Tags: javascript, методы, this

Начал изучать *JavaScript* недавно. Сейчас изучаю методы объекта и не могу понять как работает код:

```js
"use strict";

let user = {
    name: "Джон",
    hi() { console.log(this.name); },
    bye() { console.log("Пока"); }
};

user.hi();

(user.name == "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // Именно выполнение этой строки
```

Как эту строку превратить в условие `IF...ELSE` и почему при вызове мы теряем `this`? он получает `undefined`.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods тут же вроде всё расписано

Comment: код эквивалентен следующему: `var func = user.name == "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye; func();`

Answer (score -1):

```
(user.name == "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye)();
```

Данная конструкция использует [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). В первых скобках у вас возвращается строка, которая содержит объект и название метода. Переписать в if-else вариант можно так:

```
if(user.name == "Джон") {
   user.hi();
} else {
   user.bye();
}
```

this у вас находится в контексте объекта и доступен только в нем.

Comment: Ваш код не эквивалентен исходному

Comment: В if-else я переписал точно также, но результат выполнения разный. В случае с ```() ? :``` выдает то что переменная ```name = undefined```, а в случае с if-else такой ошибки нет.